# How to copy CSV file from blob container to another blob container with Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to copy any file in Blob container to another Blob container. No transformation is needed. How to do it?

However I get validate error:

```
 Copy data1:
 Dataset yellow_tripdata_2020_1 location is a folder, the wildcard file name is required for 
 Copy data1
```

[image: Source]

[image: Sink destination]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states: `the wildcard file name is required for Copy data1`.

On your data source, in the *file* field, you should enter a pattern that matches the files you want to copy. So `*.*` if you want to copy all the files, and something like `*.csv` if you only want to copy over CSV files.